# missing AddToProductSet method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am following this tutorial:

http://pattersonc.com/blog/2009/04/01/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-and-aspnet-mvc-%E2%80%93-part-i/

In the tutorial, there is a method that saves an object to the database using Entity Framework:

```
mySqlEntities.AddToProductSet(product);
```

Instead of creating a product table, I have created a table called `user`. I cannot however find any method that is like `AddToUser` or `AddToUserSet` within the `mySqlEntities` object. I have followed everything bang on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no... there are no such methods... you need to write something like this:

```
mySqlEntities.Products.Add(product);
```

Answer (score 4):

That article is outdated and looks like it has examples with Entity Framework 4, which generated [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with methods like *AddToSetName*. These methods [was marked as deprecated](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17985a91-b9a5-48bb-bea0-0a468dd64b6a/why-does-the-entity-framework-generate-deprecated-methods?forum=adodotnetentityframework) in later releases of Entity Framework and currently completely gone:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Products EntitySet.
/// Consider using the .Add method of associated ObjectSet<T> property instead.
/// </summary>
public void AddToProducts(Product product)
{
    base.AddObject("Products", product);
}
```

On Entity Framework 5 or 6 you will have [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) generated without any additional methods for sets. As Zdravko correctly pointed, you should use `context.SetName.Add` method to add entity to set.